# Data validation between different tables

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have to check if I have the product and the quantity to be sold. So, I have a table for `products` and a table for the `sales` and I have to check if it's avaliabe in stock.

I have a function to **search products by name and return a list**, I tried to check if the list is bigger than 0, but didn't work. And to find out if the quantity is valid, I tried to compare with the quantity from the `product` table.

The search function:

```cs
   public List<Produto> SearchProdName(string ProdName)
   {
     return _conexao.Table<Produto>().Where(a =>a.ProdName.Contains(ProdName)).ToList();
   }
```

```cs
    AcessoBanco acessobanco = new AcessoBanco();
    var lista = acessobanco.SearchProdName(entProdName.Text);
    if (lista.Count > 0 && produto.ProdQtde >= int.Parse(entQtde.Text))
    {
      produto.ProdQtde -= 1;
    }
```

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance! Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Edit:

Product table:

```
  public class Produto
  {
      [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
      public int ProdId { get; set; }
      public string ProdNome { get; set; }
      public string ProdMarca { get; set; }
      public int ProdQtde { get; set; }
      public string ProdDesc { get; set; }
      public string ProdFornecedor { get; set; }
      public decimal ProdRSCompra { get; set; }
      public decimal ProdRSVenda { get; set; }
      public string ProdEspecifica { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: what does "didn't work" mean?  Did it crash, give an error, or just not do what you want?  Where does `produto` come from?  If you are searching your entire table for any item that matches the name, how are you also finding the specific item they want in order to decrement the quantity?

Comment: Well, it says that I don't have that product avaliable, even when I do have. I added the ```produto```` to the post. I tried to find the item by passing it's name to the search function, as I said above.

Comment: how are you assigning the `produto` variable?  If you have already found the specific product, what is the point of search the entire table for matches?  This logic just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood what I'm trying to do. I have a sales page where it asks for the product name, among other info, so I want to check if there's a product with that name on the `produto` table.

Comment: If that's what you want, then the answer posted below should help you.  But your code has this line `if (lista.Count > 0 && produto.ProdQtde >= int.Parse(entQtde.Text))` which has a `produto` variable that comes from somewhere.  I was trying to figure out what you thought that code was doing, because it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: By doing that I ain't comparing the given product with the products in stock? 'Cause that was my intention.

Comment: "given product" implies that you have found the specific product the user wants - but you haven't shown the code that does that.  If you already have the specific product, then what is the point of getting `lista` which is a list of all products matching that name?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bring into your notice that the count function is incorrectly used in the above snippet .

To get the count of the products and with Valid Quantity (> 0) from product table .

```
public List<Product> SearchName(string Name)
{
   return _conexao.Table<Product>().Where(a =>a.ProductName.Contains(Name) && a.Quantity > 0).ToList();
}
```

To perform count validation we can use any of the below :

```
list.Count() > 0
list.Any()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it keeps telling me that I don't have the product, even if I have.

Comment: Verify the comparation `a.ProductName.Contains(Name)`, try instead `Name.Contains(a.ProductName)` I think that's the problem.

Comment: @Ivan-San It happens the same, always show the message that there's not enough products.